# How to Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable

Tags: python, django

I am trying to host a django website in gcloud... i did some changes in settings.py file
after adding the file its showing error

```
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If the flag as been set, configure to use proxy
if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432
```

after adding this code  into settings.py file i am facing  below error

```
 File "C:\Users\CHANDU\Downloads\Unisoftone\unisoftone\website\website\settings.py", line 99, 
 in <module>
 DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}
   File "C:\Users\CHANDU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
  packages\environ\environ.py", line 208, in db_url
    return self.db_url_config(self.get_value(var, default=default), engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\CHANDU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\environ\environ.py", line 281, in get_value
  raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
  django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable
```

Comment: Can you try this?
`postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname`
for sqlite,
`sqlite:///db.sqlite`

It should create sqlite db in your project root directory.

Comment: Where do you read the `.env` file that contains `DATABASE_URL` or do you export `DATABASE_URL` ?